# Ionic 2 Add Class to tab

Tags: javascript, ionic2

I have an ionic tab which I want to add a class to. (ionic v2)

`<ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Sound" tabIcon="volume-up"></ion-tab>`

I want to add the `class="pause"`nothing seems to work i tried

```
<ion-tab class="pause" [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Sound" tabIcon="volume-up"></ion-tab>
```

and examples from [here](https://www.joshmorony.com/conditional-attributes-styles-and-classes-in-ionic-2/) with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the main ionic `css is being read first before the custom styles to make sure prefix the styles like so

```
.md,.ios,.wp{
    .pause{
     // styles
    }
}
```

this will overwrite ionic styles